# My .htaccess not working on my ubuntu server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've working on my web application under ubuntu server. I would like to override or hide my index.php. I'm trying to access html GET method Pls. help, how I can not identify my error. Thanks!

<.htaccess code>

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

```
From this - http://192.168.2.60/api/index.php?url=auth
To this - http://192.168.2.60/api/auth
```

<**Error-msg:**>

Not Found
The requested URL /api/auth was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.2.60 Port 80

Comment: sidenote: the 'From this' and 'To this' is the other way round. It rewrites _from_ `api/auth` to `index.php?url=$1`

Comment: in what folder is that `.htaccess` located? root? or in `/api`?

Comment: <root_folder>/api/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I've search for multiple possible answer to work on. This post help me to work my .htaccess. I just need to enable the override at /var/www/. Here is the link it might help you guys!

[Enabling .htaccess file to rewrite path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421233/enabling-htaccess-file-to-rewrite-path-not-working)